# Spring JdbcTemplate inside a Java Servlet, how to correctly access the ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-jdbc

I would like to use the Spring framework's JdbcTemplate inside my Java servlet. I have some jdbc configuration set up as a Java class and I'm wondering the correct way to load it and use it in the servlet. Where is the best place to put this code:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JdbcConfig.class);
```

Should I create this `ApplicationContext` object on every `doGet` or `doPost` method? Or would it be better to create it once as a global variable?

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    // Should it go here as a global variable?

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        // Or Here?
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        // Or here?
    }
}
```

I ask because it seems like the jdbc configuration isn't changing, it loads when the servlet is created and then I just want to use it. At the same time, I don't know how safe that is. What if two users load the servlet at the same time, if the `ApplicationContext` is global, would that cause any problems with their queries running at the same time?
Typically, I avoid global variables in servlets for reasons like that.

Or, is loading an `ApplicationContext` not a big deal to do on every single request?

Basically, I'm wondering what happens to the `JdbcConfig` and `ApplicationContext` objects if it is loaded once when the servlet starts. Does it basically become a "static" object? Would that have a negative effect?

Note, I'm not using Spring MVC or Spring Boot, just a plain Java servlet.

Edit: My question is a how and why, I want to understand, not just troubleshoot like the linked question.

Comment: Absolutly you must NOT create it on every request. You should create it only once (in the init method of servlet) and share the same context for every servlet/class/bean

Comment: Use the servlet lifecycle `init()` hook method - within `init()` of `MyServlet` set up the context so it happens only once.

Comment: Why are you writing a servlet by hand instead of using MVC, which is built specifically to handle the repetitive parts?

Comment: @chrylis It is not my decision, I'm stuck with a plain servlet for now